# Loss of functionality: Maps v2 is soon shutting down and there is no migration path to v3 for the Youtube layer, because of the youtube api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-api-2

Maps api v2 supported a Youtube layer and it is not supported in v3, but a maps team member said it was no problem, because the youtube api supported geo queries for videos:

> Please note you can also use the YouTube API to fetch geolocated videos to create your own customized YouTube Layer, with filters and so forth.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3204#c9

The problem is the youtube api currently does not support geo queries for videos. The feature was turned off and there is unknown when it will be available again. The maps v2 api is turned off at the 19th of Nov, so sites using the v2 api with youtube layers will stop working, because there is no migration path to v3 for the youtube layer despite what the developer in the above quote said.

Is there a way to overcome this problem?